# Copying data to another worksheet (using For Each) - but the last 2 columns offset by a certain number of columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code below to copy data entered into a table into another larger database in another sheet (original question and information on my worksheets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657791/copy-data-to-first-blank-row-in-another-sheet-only-if-first-column-is-not-blank)).

```
For Each cl In Sheet2.Range("A8:A23")
    If Not IsEmpty(cl.Value) Then
        With Worksheets("Database")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 18).Value = cl.Resize(1, 18).Value
        End With
    End If
Next
```

This has been working great so far, however I've recently added another 2 columns of data into the data entry sheet (Row S & T). I need these new columns to also be pasted into the new sheet when the command button is pressed, but not into columns S & T - I want them to be pasted into columns AL & AM.

Any ideas how best to do this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go as follows:

```
With Worksheets("Database")
    For Each cl In Sheet2.Range("A8:A23").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(1, 18).Value = cl.Resize(1, 18).Value
            .Offset(, 37).Resize(, 2).Value = cl.Offset(, 18).Resize(, 2)
        End With
    Next
End With
```

where:

- I took `With Worksheets("Database")` outside the loop since it's not affected by it
- I used `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` method to directly iterate through not-blank cells and avoid the `If Not IsEmpty(cl.Value) Then` check

Comment: Thanks for the help. This code successfully copies the data in A8:R23, however it hasn't successfully copied the data in S8:T23 to anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Figured it out - just a missing ".Value" on a line. Seems to be working fine now. So thanks!